# Sending an text directly to my SMS app. Make it display as a text

Tags: java, android, sms

I am able to send a text using this following code:

```
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

But I would like to send a text message directly to my SMS app. My best example of this are "Fake Text" apps, where you put in the name and message you want sent to your phone, sadly I don't have any source code.

Comment: you need send text to system sms app or a sms app developed for you?

Comment: sms app already developed by someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android implements mechanisms to sharing data between applications. But you need add the corresponding peace of code in the sender and in the receiver application.

You can use [Content providers](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) or using [shared preferences](http://codeoncloud.blogspot.cl/2012/06/data-sharing-between-two-android.html).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ty! This looks like something I can use, although I'm pretty new at coding. I'll just see what I can do with it ^^